# Discord.py коги. RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'BotBase.load_extension' was never awaited bot.load_extension(f"cogs.{filename[:-3]}")

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно исправить код загрузки когов?
Неделю назад работал исправно.
На данный момент выдается ошибка **RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'BotBase.load_extension' was never awaited
bot.load_extension(f"cogs.{filename[:-3]}")**

Буду рад вашему ответу

```
@bot.command()
async def load(ctx, extension):
    if ctx.author.id == 436903034404995072:
        bot.load_extension(f"cogs.{extension}")
        await ctx.send("Cogs is loaded!")
    else:
        await ctx.send("**No permissions!**")


@bot.command()
async def unload(ctx, extension):
    if ctx.author.id == 436903034404995072:
        bot.unload_extension(f"cogs.{extension}")
        await ctx.send("Cogs is unloaded!")
    else:
        await ctx.send("**No permissions!**")


@bot.command()
async def reload(ctx, extension):
    if ctx.author.id == 436903034404995072:
        bot.unload_extension(f"cogs.{extension}")
        bot.load_extension(f"cogs.{extension}")
        await ctx.send("Cogs is reloaded!")
    else:
        await ctx.send("**No permissions!**")


for filename in os.listdir('./cogs'):
    if filename.endswith('.py'):
        bot.load_extension(f"cogs.{filename[:-3]}")
```

Немного переделал код и ошибка ушла, но теперь появилась проблема, что команда не находится.

Main.py

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='$', intents=discord.Intents.all())
bot.remove_command('help')


@bot.command()
async def load(ctx, extensions):
    await bot.load_extension(f'cogs.{extensions}')

for filename in os.listdir('./cogs'):
    if filename.endswith('.py'):
        async def load():
            await bot.load_extension(f'cogs.{filename[:-3]}')


bot.run(os.getenv('TOKEN'))
```

maincog.py

```
from discord.ext import commands


class MainCog:
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @commands.command(pass_context=True)
    async def test(self, ctx):
        await ctx.send('ready')


def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(MainCog(bot))
```

Возможно получились страшные вещи в коде, но это были попытки подставить await в загрузку \ отгрузку

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте перед загрузкой/отгрузкой await

Comment: Пробовал ставить await перед bot.load.extension (тоже самое в unload и reload) была такая же ошибка, потом пытался подставлять в цикл for в строку load'a и тоже тщетно

Comment: Попробовал немного переделать код и добавить еще раз await в загрузку и отгрузку. Чтобы добавить await - нужно прописать асинхронную функцию, казалось бы ошибки при запуске нет, но команда не находится. Дополнил код